# Case comments is updating multiple times

Tags: apex, trigger, case, case-comment

I have a requirement to setup email to case and with specific business criteria. And I need to update case comments for every email record created on case. So, I check the checkbox of Thread-ID and My requirement is to update case comments.

I created a field on case called Last email.And run a workflow rule on email object with criteria as created and update above field with email text body.

To update case comments i wrote a trigger with after Insert and try to update case comments.But it's updating multiple times.

**Apex Trigger**

```
trigger ForARPU on case (after insert,after update,after delete,before insert,before update) 
{
    if(Trigger.isAfter && trigger.isUpdate) 
    {
        //Updating case comments
        AccountAssignment.CaseComments(Trigger.New);
    }
}
```

**Apex Class**

```
public class AccountAssignment {
    public static void CaseComments(List<Case> CaseTriggers) 
    {
        Case myCase = CaseTriggers[0];
        if (myCase.Last_email__c!= null) {
            String caseId= myCase.ID;
            CaseComment cc = new CaseComment(
                CommentBody=myCase.Last_email__c,parentID=caseId
            );
            insert cc;
        }
    }
}
```

I just changed my apex trigger working Fine as well apex class has been modified.And i modified my code to handle records in bulk records.But please provide your suggestions for best practices

```
trigger ForARPU on case (after insert,after update,after delete,before insert,before update) 
    {

if(Trigger.isAfter && trigger.isUpdate) 
   {    
//AccountAssignment.CaseComments(Trigger.New);
  AccountAssignment.CaseUpdation(Trigger.New,Trigger.OldMap);
}
}
```

Apex class

```
Public static void CaseUpdation(List<Case> CaseNew,map<Id, Case> CaseMap) {
        List<CaseComment> caseComments = new List<CaseComment>();
        for(Case c : CaseNew){
        if ((CaseMap == null || CaseMap.get(c.Id).Last_Email__c != c.Last_Email__c) && c.Last_Email__c != null)
        {
        caseComments.add(new CaseComment(CommentBody=c.Last_Email__c,parentID=c.Id));
        }
        insert caseComments;
        }

    }
```

Let me know

Answer (score 2):

There are two common patterns to minimize recursion:

- Static flags (covered in the already written answer)
- Proper filtering (including *changes* to the filtered fields)

My recommendation here is that you filter so that you only act on records whose `Last_email__c` has changed.

```
List<Case> filtered = new List<Case>();
for (Case newRecord : newRecords)
{
    if (newRecord.Last_email__c != null &&
        (oldMap == null || newRecord.Last_Email__c != oldMap.get(newRecord.Id).Last_Email__c)
    ) filtered.add(newRecord);
}
```

Or if you install the [Selector](https://github.com/bluewolf-beyond/selector) library, you can simply do:

```
List<Case> filtered = Select.Field.hasChanged('Last_email__c').andX(
    Select.Field.hasChanged('Last_Email__c', null)
).filter(newRecords, oldMap);
```

Then just act on this filtered list instead of the original.

Comment: Adrian -- I'm not super _au fait_ with this library but don't you need a `.filter(someListOfSobjects)` method?

Answer (score 1):

Update can fire multiple times during a transaction and you are most likely running into this as an issue.

Aside from the "You should implement a Trigger Handler Framework" answer you can add a static property to limit the recursion in your current code:

**Trigger**

```
trigger ForARPU on case (after insert,after update,after delete,before insert,before update) 
{
    if(AccountAssignment.runOnce() && Trigger.isAfter && trigger.isUpdate) 
    {
        //Updating case comments
        AccountAssignment.CaseComments(Trigger.New);
    }
}
```

**Class** (adapted from sfdcFox answer [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/130086/else-part-in-test-class))

```
public class AccountAssignment {

    static Boolean flag = true;
    public static Boolean runOnce() {
        return flag && !(flag = false);
    }

    public static void CaseComments(List<Case> CaseTriggers) 
    {
        Case myCase = CaseTriggers[0];
        if (myCase.Last_email__c!= null) {
            String caseId= myCase.ID;
            CaseComment cc = new CaseComment(
                CommentBody=myCase.Last_email__c,parentID=caseId
            );
            insert cc;
        }
    }
}
```

You could place the `runOnce` code in a service / utility class if desired.

Basically this will only run the code once and on the second run of the update Trigger in the same transaction it will not enter the `AccountAssignment.CaseComments` method because the boolean will be false

Comment: Although honestly proper filters are a better solution than static flags most of the time. Just check if `Last_email__c` has changed in addition to checking if it is populated.

Comment: @AdrianLarson - Good point, Probably should add that as an answer as would be a better way to handle it and should be pointed out....All depends on the use case and a combination of both may be helpful to both reduce scope and SOQL usage

Comment: Sure, I'll add a separate answer.